# Why are errors in classes only trapped at runtime?

Tags: error-handling, vb6, ide

I have a VB6 class with a method which raises an error:

```
Public Sub DoSomething
  ...
  err.Raise 12345, description:="Error message"
  ...
End Sub
```

This method is called from a form:

```
Public Sub ErrTest()
  On Error Goto err1
  obj.DoSomething
  Exit Sub
err1:
  MsgBox err.Description
End Sub
```

This works fine at runtime, but at design time the error handling does not work. Instead the VB6 IDE displays its standard message box from where I can go into debug mode or end the program.

Why does this happen? Can I prevent it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the VB IDE, go to Tools, Option, General tab, Error trapping frame. I'm guessing you have it set to 'Break on All Errors', whereas you probably want 'Break on Unhandled Errors'.

Your `Err.Raise` statement gives a compile error for me; try removing the braces.

Also, you may want to use

```
Err.Raise vbObjectError + 12345, Description:="Error message"
```

i.e. offset your error code from the VB constant vbObjectError to be sure you don't get clashes.

Answer (score 1):

You can also change the error trapping options by right-clicking in the code window.  The following options are available from the "Toggle" sub-menu:

Break on All Errors
Break in Class Module
Break on Unhandled Errors

I find this much easier than popping up the Options dialog...

Comment: Wow, after 10+ years of opening the option dialog -- wish I had noticed this before!